# GoblinXNA - 3D objects stretched out on the Z-axis

Tags: 3d, xna

I'm using GoblinXNA to create an AR application. I copied EVERYTHING over from Tutorial 8, where basic AR Marker Recognition is established. In the tutorial itself it all built fine and the 3d objects (a sphere and a cube) are placed and rendered perfectly.

In my own project, where I copied everything to, the objects are stretched extremely over the Z-axis, if I hold the AR Tags back enough, I could see the end of the objects.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

**- Update:**

I've found out that Tutorial 8 is dependant on Tutorial 15 (GoblinXNA's OpenCV tutorial, OpenCV is used by ALVAR (the program used to recognise AR Tags) for image processing. Though I can't find anything that hints to this relation and if I try to remove Tutorial 15, Tutorial 8 bugs out explained above.

**- Update2:**

Ok, Tutorial 8 does NOT seem to be specifically related to Tutorial 15, when I delete tutorial 15 from the solution it seems to work now, but when I Rebuild the solution and then debug, it bugs out. So Tutorial 8 needs a dependancy somewhere.. Looking at it now.

**- Update3:**

Still haven't found out why my 3d objects are stretched out. I loaded a .fbx SkinnedModel (using SkinningSample / SkinnedModelProcessor) into the program, and also this object is stretched out, though in a different way. He walks around in a circle, 'around' the camera, so to say, and when the model reaches the middle of the screen, the model is extremely small, and once he starts leaving the middle towards the side of the screen he gets stretched out enormously, then he would enter the left side of the screen after a while again, stretched out, and when he gets near the center of the screen, he minimizes again, and this loops.

**- The problem has been solved!**

It seems that the Calib.xml file (Camera Calibration) was done wrong, I redid it, and this time I moved the Checkerboard paper around (used for calibration), this fixed the problems I was having with the Z-axis!

Comment: What is "AR Marker" and "AR Tags"?

Comment: @Patrik GoblinXNA is a Framework/Library where AR (=Augmented Reality) Tags are recognised via a camera and is able to show 3d objects on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem has been solved!**

It seems that the Calib.xml file (Camera Calibration) was done wrong, I redid it, and this time I moved the Checkerboard paper around (used for calibration), this fixed the problems I was having with the Z-axis!